# Typescript: type safety for interface properties in a function declaration

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have this simple example:

```
interface Steps {
  stepOne?: boolean;
  stepTwo?: boolean;
  stepThree?: boolean;
}

let steps: Steps = {};

function markStepDone (step: ???) {
  steps[step] = true;
}


markStepDone('anything');
```

How can I prevent it from allowing to pass 'anything' to this function and allow only ['stepOne', 'stepTwo', 'stepThree']?

I also tried to do it with enum, but turned out that you cannot use enum as an index signature...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `keyof` operator, which is being implemented this week (yes, really). It will look like this once it's ready:

```
function markStepDone (step: keyof Steps) {
  steps[step] = true;
}
```

An early PR with a different name (keysof) is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10425

In the meantime, `string` is a rough approximation, or the hand-written type `"stepOne" | "stepTwo" | "stepThree"` will give you the exact behavior of `keyof Steps`

Comment: Thank you! Until `keyof` is out I ended up doing something like this:  
    `type AllSteps = 'stepOne' | 'stepTwo' | 'stepThree';
    interface Steps {
      [index: string]: boolean;
    }
    function markStepDone (step: AllSteps) {`